# calculate all combination less the all value of a vector

Tags: r, matrix, vector, combinations

given a vector `c(3,4,5)` the length of vector is variable, i would return matrix  of combination with all element less the value in the vector
make like this:

```
 [x_1] [x_2] [x_3] 
[1,]  3    4     5
[2,]  2    4     5
[3,]  1    4     5 
[4,]  3    3     5
[5,]  3    2     5
[6,]  3    1     5
[7,]  2    3     5
[8,]  1    2     5
[9,]  1    4     4
[10,] 1    4     3
[11,] 1    4     2
.....
```

this is only a part of all possible combination, but i would have all possible combination.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is it.

```
x <- c(3, 4, 5)

lst <- lapply(x, ':', 1)
Map(expand.grid, list(lst))
```